# pdfbox bookmarks(outline) not displaying acute accent characters - unicode issue

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I am using `pdfbox` to create a pdf with bookmarks(page outlines). But certain characters (acute accent characters) does not get displayed well. Its been replaced by `replacement character`.

For instance the text "Chapitre 6 - Éléments", get displayed as shown below,

[image]

**Code**

```
PDDocumentOutline outline = new PDDocumentOutline();
document.getDocumentCatalog().setDocumentOutline(outline);
PDPage page = document.getPage(50);
PDPageDestination dest = new PDPageFitWidthDestination();
dest.setPage(page);
PDOutlineItem bookmark = new PDOutlineItem();
bookmark.setDestination(dest);
bookmark.setTitle("Chapitre 6 - Éléments");
outline.addLast(bookmark);
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: What PDFBox version are you using?

Comment: v2.0.21. I just figured it works as expected, when I run it within my cloud instance. But I face this issue in my local Mac. Probably missing some system fonts ?

Comment: Can you share both files?